# Fill Alphabets - Word by Word using python

Tags: python-3.x, string, list

The program must accept a string S containing multiple words as the input.The program must form a new string W based on the following conditions.
 - The number of words in S and W must be equal. 
- The length of each word in S and W must be equal. 
- The alphabets in W must be filled word by word from the alphabets in S. 
Finally, the program must print the string W as the output. 
Boundary Condition(s): 
 0 <= Length of S <= 1000 
1 <= Length of each word in S <= 20

[image: Example Input and Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a not optimized version. There probably is a shorter version with map or lambda but ...

```
def shuffle(S):
    words = S.split(' ')
    letters = sorted([c for c in S if c != ' '])
    new_words = []
    i = 0
    for l in letters:
        placed = False
        while not placed:
            if len(new_words) < len(words):
                new_words.append(l)
                placed = True
            else:
                if len(new_words[i]) < len(words[i]):
                    new_words[i] += l
                    placed = True
                i += 1
                if i == len(words):
                    i = 0
    return ' '.join(new_words)
```